# how to initialize an array of objects in a constructor in c ++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization

I try to put an array of objects as a argument,
I know that you can initialize them separately with

> constructorName (className array [], double arg2): name1 (arg1), name2(arg2){...}

But I can't do that with an array of objects, is there any other way to do this?

code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Atlet{
    private:
        string name;
        int number;
        string nacionality;
        double time;
    public:
        Atlet(string n, int num, string nacio, double t){
            name = n;
            number = num;
            nacionality = nacio;
            time = t;                
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        }
};

class Race{
    private:
        double distance;
        Atlet runners[];
    public:
        //how to initalize arrays of objects here .

        Race( Atlet arr[], double dist): runners(arr), distance(dist){
            runners = arr;
            distance = dist;          
        } 
};
```

test.cpp program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bible.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Atlet t1 = Atlet("Usaimbol",12,"Madagascar", 10.21);
    Atlet t2 = Atlet("Juan",15,"USA", 10.54);

    Atlet comps[] = {t1, t2};
    Race race1 = Race(comps, 120.00);
    return 0;
}
```

I try to  make this, but:
[image: console bug]

Comment: Are you allowed to use [standard C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)? Do you know the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html) ? Did you read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and the documentation of your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler? Are you allowed to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger?

Comment: I am a beginner in c ++, I do not know anything of what you mention, but being such an "easy" question there should be an answer, I saw many internet pages before asking, none passed an array of objects as an argument of a constructor. There are many people like me who would like to know this.
I will read your resources and use them. Thanks for help me.

Comment: My recommendation is to spend a few days in reading a good paper book about C++ programming. I even guess you could buy a good book in Spanish .....

Comment: Once you did read a good book, consider reading some C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or newer. Be aware that C++ is a very difficult programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that `Race( Atlet arr[], double dist): runners(arr), distance(dist){` should just be `Race( Atlet arr[], double dist) {` (taking out the colon stuff inline) but I cannot be certain.

Comment: if I do that, it tells me:
  error: unknown array size in delete

Comment: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
   29 |             runners = arr;

Comment: I don't understand how to declare the limit of the array, I already tried to do "runners [3];" in the "public" section.
But it doesn't work, it also asks me to set the default construct.
Total bugs: 2
-> unknow array size
-> no default constructor exists for class

Comment: Yeah, I'm sort of winging this. It looks like you would need something like ` className varableName[ arraySize ] = { } ; ` and then that constructor will initialize everything the class's default constructors. Not sure how this works though with it being a variable in a constructor for another class.

Comment: Not works, but Race( Atlet array[ 3 ] = {}, double dist=0.0){ is good idea: I tried this : Race(Atlet array[3], double dist){}, but tell me expression "runners = array" -->"must be midifiable lvalue"

Comment: Yeah I wish I new C++ better. In java that whole think would be setup like : : : 
 private double distance ;
 private String[] runners ;
 
 public Race( String[] arr, double dist )
 {
  distance = dist ;
  runners = arr ; 
 }
hopefully you can reverse engineer this into C++

Comment: yes, I know a little bit java. Thanks mattdog for help me